# How to test a MA process with extra terms for invertibility?

Tags: time-series, self-study, moving-average

I'm working on an unassessed course problem (paraphrased for brevity),

> Consider the time series model $$y_t=\alpha+\beta t+\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise and $\alpha,\beta$ are known parameters.
>
> Show that $x_t=\nabla y_t$ is not invertible.

The course notes have,

> Suppose $$y_t=h(B)\epsilon_t$$ where $$h(x)=1+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2+\dots+\beta_qx^q.$$ A moving-average process $\text{MA}(q)$ is invertible iff all roots of $h(x)=0$ lie outside the unit circle.

The solution booklet has,

> $\{x_t\}=\{\beta+\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}\}$ is not invertible as the coefficient of $\epsilon_{t-1}$ is $-1$ and does not satisfy $|-1|<1$ (alternatively $x=1$ is the only root of the MA characteristic polynomial $h(x)=1-x$, which lies on the unit circle).

But $$x_t=\beta+\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}\neq\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}=h(B)\epsilon_t.$$ What happened to the $\beta$? More generally, how does one use the root test with the characteristic MA polynomial when the form of the time series doesn't exactly match the form of $h(B)\epsilon_t$?

Comment: Hi: The $\beta$ doesn't matter because it's a constant. The only involved with invertibility of the MA are the $\epsilon_t$.

Comment: @mlofton So the statement in the course notes could be generalised to "Suppose $y_t=\beta+h(B)\epsilon_t$ for any constant $\beta$"?

Comment: Hi: yes, assuming the question is just about the invertibility of the MA. Look up what invertibiity means in a textbook ( my definition wouldn't be as good as a textbook's ) and it should be clear why that's the case. some good texts are box-jenkins-reinsel ( can't remember title ), another by rob hyndman whose title I don't know, hamilton's time-series analysis and hayashi's econometrics. or there should be a document on the net that explains it but I don't have time to google right now.